# Get Indian Standard Time(IST) in c#?

Tags: c#, datetime

When i display my system date using `DateTime.Now()` function It gives me system date and time and works fine but when i try to run this page on my server
it gives me the DateTime of Server which is outside India But i want to pick up the time of India whenever this page is executed on server.
I know it is possible through `Culture Info` Class... Any suggestion....

Comment: With the World Weather Online's Time Zone API you can get the local time for a location based on its latitude and longitude - http://mvark.blogspot.in/2013/04/how-to-show-local-time-for-location.html

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Put:

```
private static TimeZoneInfo INDIAN_ZONE = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");
```

as a field.

Then, use:

```
DateTime indianTime =  TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, INDIAN_ZONE);
```

to get the time as needed.

Comment: @Mathew `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.TimeZoneInfo' to 'System.DateTime`

Comment: @mathew `The best overloaded method match for 'System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(System.DateTime, System.TimeZoneInfo)' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: @Pandiya: Put `TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Indian Standard Time");` and then `DateTime indianTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow,tzi);`

Comment: @KMan `The time zone ID 'Indian Standard Time' was not found on the local computer.`

Comment: @Pandiya: Apologies for the typo, try "India Standard Time". Just tested it.

Comment: Sorry for my typos.  Another source had indicated that "Indian Standard Time" was correct.

Answer (score 1):

I use this method to Get current datetime from UTC and saving through Entity Framework

```
Err.Date = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time"));
```

Database Value - `2016-06-23 09:51:13.183`

Answer (score 0):

The below code works for me:

```
TimeZoneInfo INDIAN_ZONE = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Asia/Kolkata");
DateTime indianTime =  TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, INDIAN_ZONE);
Console.WriteLine(indianTime.ToString("F"));
```

Comment: This is the same as the accepted answer which was posted 10 years ago, with just the addition of a `Console.WriteLine` call. I don't think it's worth adding an answer just for that, especially as the OP wasn't asking to format anything.

Comment: It's the one written on July 16th 2010.

Comment: Ah, I see you've also changed the name of the time zone to Asia/Kolkata - I hadn't spotted that before, and your answer **didn't mention that anywhere**. (It's basically a code-only answer, with no explanation.) Note that this *won't* work on Windows - something your answer doesn't mention at all. I think calling this "the proper solution" without noting that it won't work on the OS most commonly associated with .NET is a bit odd, no?

Comment: (Basically, it would have been a lot better to add a comment to the existing answer that uses the Windows time zone ID, indicating "If you need to do the same thing on a Unix system, use "Asia/Kolkata" as the time zone ID.)

Comment: Given solution is for Windows users only, not for Unix system.

Comment: Yes, and that makes sense given that it's 10 years old, before .NET Core existed. But you didn't bother giving *any* context in the answer - you just said "This will works as expected" (which it definitely *won't* on a Windows machine). As I said, a comment on the existing answer would be much more informative than adding an answer without explaining *why* you've done so.

Comment: @Sathish in .NET 4.5 it is showing error for line

`code TimeZoneInfo INDIAN_ZONE = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Asia/Kolkata");`

//Asia/Kolkata is not supported

i think it should be

`code TimeZoneInfo INDIAN_ZONE = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");`