# Not getting exact Indian Time while Time zone converstion C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, timezone

I am trying to convert UK time to Indian Standard time in my C# code (my system time zone is in `IST`):

```
DateTime ukTime = 2015-09-02 05:03 PM; 
TimeZoneInfo INDIAN_ZONE = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");
DateTime indianTime =  TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(ukTime , INDIAN_ZONE);
```

The corresponding Indian date&time is `2015-09-02 09:33 PM`.

But I am getting output as `2015-09-02 10:36 PM` (one hour more than the expected result). How can I get the correct output?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try this link it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262067/get-indian-standard-timeist-in-c

Comment: Not sure what you're showing in the first line, but the rest of the code is correct.  If you're getting the wrong time, then your clock is not set correctly.

Comment: First line is still not valid C#, but I will assume you mean it to be a `DateTime` with that value?

Comment: yes..i Just shown the date time value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant to do this:

```
DateTime ukTime = new DateTime(2015, 9, 2, 17, 3, 0); // 2015-09-02 05:03 PM
TimeZoneInfo UK_ZONE = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");
TimeZoneInfo INDIAN_ZONE = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");
DateTime indianTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(ukTime, UK_ZONE, INDIAN_ZONE);

// 2015-09-02 09:33 PM
```

"UK time" is not the same as UTC or GMT.  The United Kingdom only follows GMT for part of the year.  The other part of the year, it is in British Summer Time (BST), which is UTC+1.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I will try this and update to you by tomorrow.

Comment: And the UK is currently in BST, until 25 October.