# How to convert PST time to IST time in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have data and timing in PST: 
  **2017-12-14 22:23:21**

I want to convert this timing into IST format.

can someone please tell me how to do this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: add the number of hours diff to the time

Comment: or you can save the time in utc format and then add 5.30 hours to the time

Comment: I recommend using NodaTime over adding hours as suggested by ArijitMukherjee.

Comment: well I agree to @Amy, you can check the answer I have given a solution might help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Indian Standard Time(IST) in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262067/get-indian-standard-timeist-in-c)

Comment: the time which i have written is in PST format, i want to convert this to IST format

Comment: PST and IST aren't *formats*.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static TimeZoneInfo INDIANTIME = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");


DateTime indianTime =  TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, INDIANTIME);
```

Save the datetime in utc and then apply this.